# Running SharePoint 2013 Manual Workflow triggers List Update workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I have a SharePoint 2013 list, within it I have a workflow that starts when a list item is updated.  This workflow emails people regarding a data change to the list.
I also have a second workflow on that list that can only be run manually which will do some reporting on demand for an item on the list (user checks an item, goes to Workflows, and runs it).

The problem is:  When the second manual reporting workflow runs, it also causes the list item update workflow to trigger, which in turn spams my users when no real data change occurred (other than the workflow status field), or at least, it's not a data change that I care about.

Question:  How do I prevent the "update workflow" from starting when I'm running the manually-started reporting workflow?

Comment: After the manually started workflow run, what is the value of the ModifiedBy field? Is it the name of the user that started the workflow or is it the name of the system account? If its the system account, one solution would be, in the update workflow, to begin by checking if the item has been update by the system. If so, do nothing. Another solution would be to create a hidden field in the list as a tracking mechanism. You update this field using the manually started workflow and you verify for the value of this field in the update workflow.

Comment: Those are great suggestions, thank you!  The modified by is the person that ran the workflow.  It would be nice if it were the opposite.  I also tried doing a semaphore in my list, but the problem there is I have to reset it back to "Go" mode when my manual workflow ends, and that triggers the update workflow again.  I think my best solution is to put the semaphore field into a separate "control" list.